# How to make Doctrine hydrator populate the entity?

Tags: zend-framework, orm, doctrine-orm

Here's what I have so far,

Form:

```
use DoctrineModule\Stdlib\Hydrator\DoctrineObject as Hydrator;
class UserRegisterForm extends
Form implements InputFilterProviderInterface
{
    public function __construct($entityManager)
    {
        parent::__construct('Practitioner');

        $this
            ->setAttribute('method', 'post')
            ->setHydrator(new Hydrator($entityManager), 'App\Entity\Users', true)
            ->setObject(new Users())
        ;

        // add fields here ...
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
class UsersController extends AbstractActionController {

public function addAction()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $form = new PractitionerRegisterForm($this->getEntityManager());
    $users = new \App\Entity\Users;
    $form->bind($users);

    if ( $request->isPost() ) {
        $form->setData($request->getPost());
        // echo pre var_dump($this) /pre
        $users->getDetails();
    } else {
        // do something here
    }

    return ['form' => $form];
}
```

but what I'm getting from `$users->getDetails()` is attributes with NULL

So how do I use Hydrator to populate the entity Users?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:** I had to validate the form by using `$form->isValid()` which validates then hydrates(populates) the entity.